# How to check javascript boolean value in XSLT

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I'm trying to update my XML data based on some javascript boolean variables in XSLT, I'm not sure what is the best way to use it. I tried below code but it seems it's not working. Could you please help me out.

**Javascript:**

```
<msxsl:script language="JScript" implements-prefix="usr">
  <![CDATA[
            var FDAttempt = false;
            function setFDAttemptTrue()
            {
              FDAttempt = true;
            }
            function getFDAttempt()
            {
                return FDAttempt;
            }
        ]]>
</msxsl:script>
```

**Setting the variable in one of the Templates**

```
<xsl:template name="FDTemplate">
  <xsl:if test ="usr:setFDAttemptTrue()" />
  <Tran>
    <TranName>FDAttempt</TranName>
    <Result>Forced</Result>
  </Tran>
</xsl:template>
```

**Checking the boolean value: Is this the correct way to check**

```
<xsl:when test ="Content/Journal">
  <xsl:variable name="x" select ="Content/*[1]" />
    <xsl:variable name="ForcedAttempt" select="usr:getFDAttempt()" />

     <xsl:if test ="$x/Name='Complete' and $x/Details='Error' and $ForcedAttempt='false'">
        <OutPut>
          <Name>SDM</Name>
          <Location>Transport</Result>
        </OutPut>
      </xsl:if>

</xsl:when>
```

Comment: Which XSLT processor do you use? Instead of `and $ForcedAttempt='false'` I would use `and not($ForcedAttempt)`. But whether any of those attempts to maintain a state in an extension script variable are going to work is highly implementation dependent.

Comment: @Martin Honnen, Thanks for your quick response. I use XSLT 1.0.I will try your fix.

Comment: @Martin Honnen. Sorry to respond you lately. I tried with $ForcedAttempt and it worked fine and it doesn't cause ant problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Programming XSLT code that tries to get away with side-effects is a constant battle against the optimizer. You're quite likely to find that an instruction like

```
<xsl:if test ="usr:setFDAttemptTrue()" />
```

gets optimized away because it produces an empty result whether or not the test condition is true.

And your example doesn't really convince me that using extension functions and side-effects is needed to solve the problem you are tackling. (I would be more likely to be convinced if you described the problem.) As far as I can see, what you are doing could be achieved with simple `xsl:param`/`xsl:with-param` mechanisms.